# Autovacuum postgresql 11 with big tables and many updates

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, devops

I have a problem with my database Postgresql 11.

1. I have database with many rows 10+ millions.
2. I analyzed of my the biggest tables (open picture):[left side was one day, right side is next day (24  hour)]
   [image: 1] - 60+ million updates and 30+ million updates everyday
3. I'm using autovacuum:

```
autovacuum = on
vacuum_cost_delay = 0
vacuum_cost_page_hit = 0
vacuum_cost_page_miss = 1
vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 1
vacuum_cost_limit = 10000
autovacuum_max_workers = 3
autovacuum_naptime = 1s
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50
autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.00
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 5ms
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1
```

4. I have monitoryng of dead tuples:
   [image: Graph] Its near 600+k tuples every time with vacuum config.

Problem: The base grows daily by 7-10 gigabytes! After Vacuum Full base size is 69GB but after one week it take 110-115 GB. So, how can I change the config so that the database stops growing?
I cant up vacuum workers and autovacuum_cost_limit is max value.
I would like to take some experience from someone because i'm just junior DevOps)

Comment: Do you have a graph of size over time?  Is the growth uniform or is it approaching a plateau?  What measure of size are you looking at? pg_total_relation_size, pg_table_size, or something else?  Is this the combined size for all three tables, or just the biggest of them?

Comment: I would say your problem is not due to a shortage of vacuuming, and so "vacuum even harder" is not the answer.

Comment: @jjanes Im just doung du -sh /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/base
I cant say for sure about uniform growth because i havent got monitoring size of database, Im doing it by hands once day... Every day it grows by 5-7 gigabytes.
And i think the same about that "vacuum is not the answer" because it was a problem from backend of project...
I did like Laurenz-Albe sad, but without default settings. So, will see tommorow how it will work

Comment: I suspect the bloat is happening in an index, as space reuse in indexes is much more constrained than in tables.  You should look at the size of each index of each table.  But unless you already know each index size after the VACUUM FULL, you wouldn't have anything to compare them to see the growth.  You could reindex them one by one to see how much each shrinks.

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Comment: @jjanes - u was right. The problem was in indexes... The size of the tables remains in place, but the size of the indexes grows rapidly due to constant updates. While doing the REINDEX, he squeezed them, but they also begin to grow. I found out that ordinary vacuum does not compress them, even if there is a "vacuuming index" stage ...
So... Is it a good practise, to start REINDEX every week at night? or maybe there is some kind of automatic index rebuilding?

Answer (score 2):

Reset all these parameters back to the default setting, and change the cost delay for the table in question:

```
ALTER TABLE large SET (autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0);
```

This makes autovacuum on that table as fast as possible.

In addition, set `maintenance_work_mem` high for best autovacuum performance.

Comment: is it make Autovacuum faster? The vacuum will have time to clean, as i understand this option

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer.

Comment: After one day - the same
600k dead tuples every time

Comment: If they are really *the same* dead tuples, and if autovacuum completed (you should set `log_autovacuum_min_duration` to get a log entry), then there is a long running transaction or something else that prevents `VACUUM` from cleaning up. You should investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of indexes are these?  Assuming the most common (btree):

Vacuuming indexes does not shrink them, it only frees up space for internal reuse.  And that space reuse is tightly constrained.  Space can only be reused if the new tuple naturally belongs on that page (given the value of the other remaining tuples already there) or if the page is entirely empty then the whole page can be marked available to be linked into some other place in the tree.

So for example if you have an user table which is never deleted from and has an index on/starting with a timestamptz column "last_logged_on", then as your users drop out they will never get that column updated anymore, while all their former (still active) neighbors will have moved away to other index pages.  Eventually you will build up long strings of index pages marking the last time former customers logged in, with only one or a few customers per index page. (Any index page containing zero former customers should have been delinked and reused already).

As another example, if you have a lot of transient customers who eventually get deleted, and only small fraction stick around long term, then you can get the same thing with the index on their customer_id if it is populated by a sequence.  Each long term customer could end up on an index page by themselves, as the transients end up getting deleted from around them.

These problems generally develop quite slowly and can be fixed easily with a rare REINDEX (which can now (>= v12) be done CONCURRENTLY, meaning without locking out ordinary INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE from the table).